# Regex for a semicolon-separated list

Tags: regex

I have a list of words consisting of 1 or more `a` characters, separated by semicolons. The list can be empty. Is it possible to write a single regex expression that will match all possible valid lists and nothing else?
Valid lists:

```
''
'a'
'aaaaa'
'a;a'
'aaa;a'
'a;aaaaa;aaa'
```

Invalid lists:

```
';aa'
'a;'
';'
'aaa;;a'
```

The closest thing I could come up with was either:

```
^(a+)*(;a+)*$
```

which matches an invalid `;a` or:

```
^(a+)+(;a+)*$
```

which doesn't match the valid empty list.

Comment: [`^(a+(?:;a+)*)?$`](https://www.regex101.com/r/4Ubi8R/2)

Comment: @Tushar put that in an answer, so that I can +1 it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`^(a+(?:;a+)*)?$`](https://www.regex101.com/r/4Ubi8R/2)

1. `a+`: Match `a` one or more times
2. `(?:;a+)*`: Match one or more `a` zero or more times
3. `(...)?`: To match `''`(empty string)

Here's demo using HTML

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="(a+(?:;a+)*)?" placeholder="Type here" />
```

Same regex can also be written with OR(`|`) as

[`^(a+(?:;a+)*|)$`](https://www.regex101.com/r/4Ubi8R/3)

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="(a+(?:;a+)*|)" placeholder="Type here" />
```

Comment: Why is one group capturing and the other non-capturing?

Comment: @NPS No specific reason. When started writing regex, the outer group was not present. Added it later to allow empty match.